# How can I add a simple custom field to my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, forms, user-meta

I have a custom plugin that I'm trying to edit. I didn't develop the plugin. I just need to add a textarea to it and save the contents. I have the field added, but I can't get it to save. This simply needs to be on the backend in the admin. This field will not be visible anywhere but this page.

Here's my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 15%;">CHEF Account Info</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'Status', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" readonly="" onfocus="this.select()" value="<?php echo $chef_config->get_chef_status_title( $user->chef_status ); ?>" class="regular-text">
                    <?php if ( $user->chef_status == 'rejected' ): ?>
                        <br><br><textarea name="chef_status_rejection_notes" readonly="" onfocus="this.select()" class="um-forms-field um-long-field" rows="6"><?php echo $user->chef_status_rejection_notes; ?></textarea>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'User Role', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" readonly="" onfocus="this.select()" value="<?php echo $chef_config->get_chef_role_title( $user->roles[0] ); ?>" class="regular-text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'Experience Level', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" readonly="" onfocus="this.select()" value="<?php echo $user->chef_experience_level; ?>" class="regular-text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'Registered', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" readonly="" onfocus="this.select()" value="<?php echo date_format( date_create( $user->user_registered ), "F j\, Y @ h:i:s A" ); ?>" class="regular-text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'Resources Access', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $terms = get_terms('resource_category');
                        $chef_profile_resources_access = $user->chef_profile_resources_access;
                        if ( empty( $chef_profile_resources_access ) ) {
                            $chef_profile_resources_access = [];
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php $terms = get_terms('resource_category'); ?>
                    <select name="chef_profile_resources_access[]" multiple>
                        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" <?php if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $chef_profile_resources_access ) ): echo 'selected'; endif; ?>><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'Reporting Form', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $form_pages = get_pages( ['parent' => 1520 ] );
                        $chef_profile_reporting_form = $user->chef_profile_reporting_form;
                        if ( empty( $chef_profile_reporting_form ) ) {
                            $chef_profile_reporting_form = '';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <select name="chef_profile_reporting_form">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                        <?php foreach ( $form_pages as $page ): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" <?php if ( $page->ID == $chef_profile_reporting_form ): echo 'selected'; endif; ?>><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><label><?php echo _e( 'CHEF Notes', 'chef' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><textarea id="chef_profile_notes" rows="5" onfocus="this.select()" value="<?php echo $user->chef_profile_notes; ?>" class="regular-text" /> </textarea></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="user-approve-reject-actions">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_permissions" />
        <button class="button button-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My textarea is at the bottom. What do I need to do to get it to save?

Comment: Set a `name` for your `textarea` - `<textarea name="chef_profile_notes"...>`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Every other field in that form works. This is a brand new field...am I missing a hook or action somewhere?

Comment: The `textarea` should also be in this format: `<textarea name="chef_profile_notes" ...><?php echo esc_textarea( $user->chef_profile_notes ): ?></textarea>`

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, but I have written a proper answer and I hope it helps you more.

Comment: note you may need to use `stripslashes` on the textarea data before saving if you want to use quotes to be in the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `textarea` needs to have a proper `name` in order for the browser to send it to the server for processing such as be saved to a database.

Secondly, `textarea` fields do not have a `value` and they also need a closing tag `</textarea>` because `textarea` is a multi-line form field.

So the proper format is:

```
<textarea name="chef_profile_notes" id="chef_profile_notes" ...other attributes...>
  <?php echo esc_textarea( $user->chef_profile_notes ): ?><!-- the field value -->
</textarea>
```

And you can see I also use [`esc_textarea()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_textarea) which is to secure the output sent/displayed to the user. See [Data Validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin use ajax to save data, ajax call the  `user_permissions` function that is already defined in the plugin classes, if you can share this function, may you found how data is structured and saved and you could add yours.